# web font stopped working in firefox only

Tags: html, fonts

Not sure what I did but it was working fine until a few days ago.

http://www.thegiftinsider.com/beta/

There should be three fonts through out the site... It works on my browser and few others, but then theres ones not working. Any ideas?

The three fonts are:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:BodoniSvtyTwoITCTTBookIta;
    src:url(fonts/bod72wi-webfont.eot);
    src:url(fonts/bod72wi-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype), url(fonts/bod72wi-webfont.woff) format(woff), url(fonts/bod72wi-webfont.ttf) format(truetype), url(fonts/bod72wi-webfont.svg#BodoniSvtyTwoITCTTBookIta) format(svg);
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:AvenirLight;
    src:url(fonts/avenilig-webfont.eot);
    src:url(fonts/avenilig-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype), url(fonts/avenilig-webfont.woff) format(woff), url(fonts/avenilig-webfont.ttf) format(truetype), url(fonts/avenilig-webfont.svg) format(svg);
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:NotepadRegular;
    src:url(fonts/notepad_-webfont.eot);
    src:url(fonts/notepad_-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype), url(fonts/notepad_-webfont.woff) format(woff), url(fonts/notepad_-webfont.ttf) format(truetype), url(fonts/notepad_-webfont.svg#NotepadRegular) format(svg);
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that FF is using the eot font file instead of the .woff file that it can render.

Its likely a mistake in the css above.

have you tried generating the fonts using the Font [Squirrel Font Face Generator?](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)
have you tried to format your css declaration using the [bulletproof css declaration](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)?

**edit:** try this (single quotes added):

```
    @font-face {
        font-family:'BodoniSvtyTwoITCTTBookIta';
        src:url('fonts/bod72wi-webfont.eot');
        src:url('fonts/bod72wi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
            url('fonts/bod72wi-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
            url('fonts/bod72wi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
            url('fonts/bod72wi-webfont.svg#BodoniSvtyTwoITCTTBookIta') format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, If you look down (scroll right - i made it into one line) the sources I have ttf, svg and woff.

Comment: Hi Mako, i suggest you try the Font Squirrel FOnt Face Generator, it will generate the syntax you need. If you want to go in depth into the syntax, check out the bulletproof css declaration article

Comment: Yup, I used Font squirrel in the first place.  I'm wondering if it has to do with me removing the breaks in the lines.

Comment: maybe single quotes should be added to the font-family property value? i.e. font-family:'BodoniSvtyTwoITCTTBookIta' ?

Comment: Try it with all the quotes added, i can post an example.